# XCode: Is it possible to create reusable stack views?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

Is it possible to create reusable stack views on the story board that can be used dynamically to be generated at a later time? Sort of a template/widget/component.

I am aware that I can do this with a class but if I am able to visually generate a set of components that can be re-used at a latter time I may be able to let our designers make changes to storyboards directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- you can do this with any UIView. There are many tutorials for this (e.g. http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/07/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard/)

The basic idea is to drag one onto Storyboard or XIB, make a custom class for it, then implement the view's `awakeFromNib` to load it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.It is.

1. Create a empty xib and then add a stack view to it.
2. Then create a class which extends UIStackView.

   ```
   class stackView: UIStackView {

   var contentView : UIStackView!
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       xibSetup()
   }

   required init(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       xibSetup()    }

   func xibSetup() {
       contentView = loadViewFromNib() 
       contentView.frame = bounds
       contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
       addSubview(contentView)
   }

   func loadViewFromNib() -> UIStackView! {

       let view: UIStackView? = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("stackView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! UIStackView?
       return view
   }
   ```
3. Create a viewController.Add a stackView to it.In StackView properties, goto 3rd bar which named as custom class, for class name give stackView class name